# Did karna learn the vedas from Drona?

Tags: mahabharata, dharma-shastras, karna, varna, dronacharya

I am looking for explicit mention in KMG Mahabharata that Karna learnt vedas from Drona (will be helpful if there are passages that show he conducted vedic rites). I don't think he learnt vedas from Parshurama but I might be mistaken.

The reason being Manusmriti and other dharma shastras seem to indicate that children born out of Pratiloma marriages (e.g. Suta) are not eligible to learn vedas. So any reference will be helpful .

EDIT

I came across the following in Udyoga Parva

> O son of Radha, thou hast worshipped many Brahmanas fully conversant with the **Vedas**. With concentrated attention and mind free from envy thou hast also (on many an occasion) enquired of them after truth. Thou knowest, therefore, O Karna, what the eternal saying of the **Vedas** are.

Seems that he had knowledge of the vedas after all. But does it mean sutas can learn vedas? Even Vayu Purana seem to say otherwise verse 28-29

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It was not mentioned in KMG's version of Mahabharata that Karna learnt vedas from Drona.  The following is an extract from that version.

After being rejected by Drona, for getting the Brahma weapon, [Karna approached Parasurama](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12a002.htm).

> Approaching Rama, he bent his head unto him and said, 'I am a Brahmana
> of Bhrigu's race.' This procured honour for him. With this knowledge
> about his birth and family, Rama received him kindly and said,
>
> 'Thou art welcome!' at which Karna became highly glad.
>
> While residing on the Mahendra mountains that resembled heaven itself,
> Karna met and mixed with many Gandharvas, Yakshas, and gods.
> ***Residing there he acquired all the weapons duly***, and became a great favourite of the gods, the Gandharvas, and the Rakshasas.

---

The purpose of Karna's approaching Parasurama is to learn Brahma weapon, but not to learn the Veda.

Comment: Yes, I know Drona refused to teach Karna how to wield the Brahma weapon. However I am interested in the teaching of vedas. As we know Drona was preceptor of Karna before Parashurama

Comment: @Carmensandiego: KMG's version is silent on this issue.  Link was already provided in my answer.  You can check for yourself that Parasurama did not teach the Veda to Karna

Comment: Yes. I mentioned in my question that it is unlikely he learnt vedas from Parashurama.